# Why can't Django find an object contains unicode like this?

Tags: python, django, unicode

For example, one of an object contains `this_sub_string`:

```
>> repr(this_sub_string)
u'1 \u03bcM rosiglitazone / 0.1% DMSO for 1 hour'`
```

in its `description` field. But when I use `objects.all.filter(Q(description__contains=this_sub_string))` to search object like this, there is no results returned.

When I eliminate the strings before `\u03bcM` to search, I can get the right results

```
>>> models.Samples.objects.filter(description__contains=u' rosiglitazone / 0.1% DMSO for 1 hour')
[<Samples: 40171_GSM1199141_CBP CHIP-SEQ, 3T3-L1 DAY7 1H ROSI_Mus musculus>, <Samples: 40172_GSM1199139_RNAPII CHIP-SEQ, 3T3-L1 DAY7 1H ROSI REP2_Mus musculus>, <Samples: [Bad Unicode data]>, <Samples: 40176_GSM\
1199143_INPUT, 3T3-L1 DAY7 1H ROSI_Mus musculus>, <Samples: [Bad Unicode data]>, <Samples: 40180_GSM1199133_MED1 CHIP-SEQ, 3T3-L1 DAY7 1H ROSI_Mus musculus>, <Samples: [Bad Unicode data]>, <Samples: 40185_GSM119\
9137_RNAPII CHIP-SEQ, 3T3-L1 DAY7 1H ROSI REP1_Mus musculus>]

>>> models.Samples.objects.filter(description__contains=u' rosiglitazone / 0.1% DMSO for 1 hour')[0].description
u'{"source name": "3T3-L1 adipocytes (Day 7)", "treatment": "1 \\u03bcM rosiglitazone / 0.1% DMSO for 1 hour", "cell type": "3T3-L1 adipocytes", "chip antibody": "anti-CBP (sc-369; Santa Cruz)"}'
```

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

This part make me think that You are storing not string itself but representation of `dict` containing this string or `json` dump of it.

```
>>> models.Samples.objects.filter(description__contains=u' rosiglitazone / 0.1% DMSO for 1 hour')[0].description
u'{"source name": "3T3-L1 adipocytes (Day 7)", "treatment": "1 \\u03bcM rosiglitazone / 0.1% DMSO for 1 hour", "cell type": "3T3-L1 adipocytes", "chip antibody": "anti-CBP (sc-369; Santa Cruz)"}'
```

In this case Unicode character will be present in database as `\u03bcM` but not utf-8 character

To search using this string one should process it same way (`json` dump or `repr`)

Answer (score 0):

I find a hacking to solve this problem

```
from _json import encode_basestring_ascii as c_encode_basestring_ascii

>>> c_encode_basestring_ascii(a)
'"1 \\u03bcM rosiglitazone / 0.1% DMSO for 1 hour"'
```

Then the query can return the right result..